# Cannot read property of undefined in if

Tags: javascript

i want to check if something is set...

```
    if(typeof app.user.case.item_unbox.image["600px"] != 'undefined') {
        app.user.winnings.image = app.user.case.item_unbox.image["600px"];
    } else {
        app.user.winnings.image = app.user.case.item_unbox.image;
    }
```

But there i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '600px' of undefined when i dont give it. But than i want `app.user.case.item_unbox.image`

How can i do that? I also tried

```
if(app.user.case.item_unbox.image["600px"]) {
```

There i get the same error... Cause its not set. But thats okay... cause than i will set the else...

Comment: `image` is undefined. Check what `item_unbox` is. It's probably not what you think.

Comment: A tip would be to put a debugger; before that line so you can check in your browsers console what options you have available

Comment: `if(!!app.user.case.item_unbox.image &&!!app.user.case.item_unbox.image["600px"]  )`

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `app.user.case.item_unbox.image` is undefined and hence you need to provide a check like

```
const img = app.user.case.item_unbox.image;
if(img && img["600px"]) {
    app.user.winnings.image = img["600px"];
} else {
    app.user.winnings.image = img;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case your image prop is the undefined one, so...

```
if(app.user.case.item_unbox.image && app.user.case.item_unbox.image["600px"])
```

Should work